# Symmetric power of Euler sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Is there 'good' representation for the sheaf $\ker(S^2V^* \otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V)} \twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V)}(2))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sheaf $K$ fits into the following exact sequence
$$
0 \to S^2(\Omega(1)) \to K \to \Omega(2) \to 0.
$$

Comment: Any hints on how to prove it?

Comment: If there is an exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$, there is a filtration on $S^nB$ by images of natural maps $S^kA \otimes S^{n-k}B \to S^nB$; its factors are $S^kA \otimes S^{n-k}C$. Using this for the Euler sequence one obtains the above exact sequence.